# Error in `./2': free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000096044c *** Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I am new to c++ and I just had this error for my program when I am deleting my pointer that points to the integer array.Here is part of my code.

```
int *list=new int[20]; 

ifstream in;
in.open(xxx);
for(a = 0; a < 10; a++){
in >> *list
list++;}

delete[] list;

list = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're changing `list` in for loop. When loop ends, `list` is not pointing to the original position allocated, `delete[]` on it will be [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can use `operator[]` in for loop to avoid the changing of `list`, such as

```
for(a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    in >> list[a];
}
delete[] list;
```

Or use a local variable

```
int* p = list;
for(a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    in >> *p;
    p++;
}
delete[] list;
```

Answer (score 1):

`list++` `delete list;` ?

You need to go back and look at pointers etc again. By doing `list++` you are changing the value of `list`, so when you say `delete [] list` the value isn't the one you allocated.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer passed to `delete` must be the same exact pointer that was returned by `new`.

Your code takes the value returned by `new`, and places it into a pointer.

Afterwards, your code proceeds and do a few things, which also includes incrementing the pointer, before calling `delete`.